# How can one measure the speed of light in MPH?

Tags: speed-of-light, unit-conversion

so, how can we actually do it?

Its well known that the speed of light is a certain number of miles per second, but if its never been tested, how do we get that number?

Comment: I've taught labs in which undergraduate students measure the speed of light by comparing travel times for a laser beam traveling over two different optical paths. It is actually pretty easy to measure c this way.

Comment: The laser beam method is basically the same as what was done with mechanical apparatus in the 19th century. See https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fizeau%E2%80%93Foucault_apparatus

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[Its pretty straight forward](https://sciencing.com/calculate-speed-light-5157189.html)

> Measuring the Speed of Light from Astronomical Observations
>
> Roemer was the first person to come up with a number for the speed of
>   light. He did it while observing the eclipses of of Jupiter's moons,
>   specifically Io. He would watch Io disappear behind the giant planet
>   and then time how long it took to reappear. He reasoned that this time
>   could differ by as much as 1,000 seconds, depending on how close
>   Jupiter was to the earth. He came up with a value for the speed of
>   light of 214,000 km/s, which is in the same ballpark as the modern
>   value of almost 300,000 km/s.
>
> In 1728, English astronomer James Bradley calculated the speed of
>   light by observing stellar aberrations, which is their apparent change
>   in position due to the earth's motion around the sun. By measuring the
>   angle of this change and subtracting the speed of the earth, which he
>   could calculate from data known at the time, Bradley came up with a
>   much more accurate number. He calculated the speed of light in a
>   vacuum to be 301,000 km/s.

Comment: I believe Roemer observed eclipses, where the moon enters/leaves Jupiter's *shadow*.

Answer (score 1):

You can't measure it! Not since 1983. The speed of light is defined to be 299,792,458 metres per second - because in the SI system  the metre is defined to be the distance light travels in 1/299792458 of a second. A mile is nowadays defined to be 1,609.344 metres, and an hour is just 3600 seconds, so that's  670,616,629 mph.

So you can't measure it. It's defined. These undergraduate experiments with laser beams are actually calibrating the metre rules and/or clocks used in the apparatus.

$c=299,792,458 ms^{-1}$. That's not a measurement. That's the law.

Comment: Technically the OP asked about measuring the speed of light in mph, so SI definitions won't apply.

Comment: but the mile is now defined in terms of the metre.  And of course the hour is defined in terms of the second.

Comment: If you take your argument all the way then you also can't measure a meter or a second.